# How to trigger multiple jobs based on the condition?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops

I have a simple 3 jenkins job A,B,C down streamed to a master job which has to say the condition which all jobs have to triggered (A,B,C). (how this can be done)

Condition 1: When the B&C combination is given it can execute the downstream parallel.

Condition 2: If A job comes in condition like A&B or A&C or A,B&C. The B&C job has to be triggered when only the A job is successful if not it should not be triggered.

Can you please help me out in achieving this flow.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this out: https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/01/19/converting-conditional-to-pipeline/

Comment: @JonyD Thanks for your reply is it possible to execute a job instead of the execute shell in the build process.